# Laravel Authorization Policy AccessDeniedHttpException This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, model, authorization

I have this setup:-

\App\Policies\ObservationPolicy

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Observation;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ObservationPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(User $user, Observation $observation)
    {
        return $user->id == $observation->user_id;
    }



}
```

Auth Service provider :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;


class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\Observation' => 'App\Policies\ObservationPolicy'
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

When i tried in view file with this statement :-

```
@can('edit', $observation)
@endcan
```

It worked without any issue.

But when i used in Controller :

```
public function edit($id,Observation $observation)
    {
        $this->authorize('edit', $observation);
        return view('mypage');
    }
```

it always return error :-
AccessDeniedHttpException
This action is unauthorized

The route that i accessed is :-
Route::get('/Observation/{id}/edit', 'ObservationController@edit');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're accepting the wrong parameters in your controller method.

The route you have defined:

```
Route::get('/Observation/{id}/edit', 'ObservationController@edit');
```

is going to pass along the `$id`, but I think the `Observation $observation` is just making a new instance of the Observation class.
It's happening because Laravel thinks you want to use dependency injection in your controller method: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

```
public function edit($id, Observation $observation):
```

---

**Instead** try this in your route:

```
Route::get('/Observation/{observation}/edit', 'ObservationController@edit');
```

and this as your method parameters:

```
public function edit(Observation $observation):
```

Here we use the build-in feature to do route model binding:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding
If you don't want to rely on that magic, you would have to find the actual observation inside your controller method manually, for example `$observation = Observation::findOrFail($id);`